# Using column content from table A in the WHERE statement of table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't been able to work out how to do this.  It may not be doable, or the experts here may say its a very bad way to do this.

Say I have `tableA` which has a list of `questions` I want to ask of my dataset.  I have my `SELECT` statement set up with an empty `WHERE` statement.  I want to read each row of `tableA` and use the conditions listed in it in my `WHERE` statement.

How would I bring in the results from Table A, one row at a time, so that they are displayed and used in the `SELECT`/`WHERE` statement of my main SQL?

Does this make sense?

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking at dynamic sql for this, which means you may also be at risk for sql injection attacks, depending on how the conditions are added to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Let's suppose you have table `tableA` with those where conditions:

```
create table tableA (condition varchar(max));
insert into tableA values ('columnB1 > 0'), ('columnB2 <> ''Me''');
```

And `tableB`, the table that we will apply those conditions to:

```
create table tableB (columnB1 int, columnB2 varchar(10));
insert into tableB values (-1, 'Not me'), (1, 'Me');
```

Now, you can use dynamic SQL, it will create separate query for each row in `@tableA`:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = '';
select @sql = @sql + ' select * from MY_DATABASE.dbo.tableA where ' + condition
from tableA

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: This answer is a good one, +1 from my side, but the *quirky update* (`select @sql = @sql + ...`) may lead to unexpected results... This might be one of the rare cases to use a cursor or rather use `FOR XML PATH('')` to aggregate the string...

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand you can also use nested select, First Select write a query for one row and After again select from it.